# Error when adding files to zip using Ionic.Zip.ZipFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> I am getting an error: System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.
> I am getting this error when trying to add files from the server into a zipfile.

```
public ActionResult DownloadStatements(string[] years, string[] months, string[] radio, string[] emails, string acctNum)
    {
        
        List<string> manypaths = (List<string>)TempData["temp"];
        
        using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
        {   
            zip.AddFiles(manypaths, @"\" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            zip.Save(output);
            return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip");
        }
    }
```

> I am getting the error in the line "zip.AddFiles(manypaths, @"" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
> Each file is coming from the server and they are pdfs. the path file looks like:\\ftp-RTMT01\PDF_STORAGE\03_31_2017\Deposit\123_Deposit_03_31_2017_1.pdf".
> None of these are duplicates so I don't understand this error message. Had it for about 2 days now.

Comment: could you show us a sample "manypaths". Is it a directory structure or just a list of files in a single folder?

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota so the manypaths will be 3 to however many files I am grabbing. So it could be 50 or 20 files. each files path looks like this \\GHT-RTMT01\PDF_STORAGE\03_31_2017\Deposit\123_Deposit_03_31_2017_1.pdf".
But all of them are different dates and such so I know none of them are duplicates.

Comment: According to the documentation, "Any directory structure that may be present in the filenames contained in the list is "flattened" in the archive.". So, even if there are same name files in two different folders, it may be a problem.